# Как заставить rake не выводить backtrace в случае ошибки?

Tags: ruby, rake

Использую `rake` и его `Rakefile` для автоматизации сборки и генерации документации. Удобный инструмент, но есть одна проблема.

В случае, если вызываемая команда (через `sh`) возвращает статус не ноль, то это рассматривается как ошибка, и бросается исключение, а выполнение `task` останавливается. Такое поведение меня устраивает, но из-за выброса исключения показывается длинный ruby-backtrace, который меня не интересует вообще, лишь скрывает от меня ошибки компилятора.

Искал, как можно отключить этот backtrace, нашёл такое решение:

```
sh "some command" do |t, ok|
  puts "error" if not ok
end
```

Работает, выполнение останавливается, backtrace не выводится. Но если использовать как зависимость в другом `task`, то это не работает: обрывается выполнение `task` с ошибкой, и он считается выполненным корректно, что является неправильным поведением.

Как заставить `rake` не выводить backtrace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rakefile:

```
desc "lol"
task :lol do

  sh "touch /1"
end
```

Запускаем:

```
$ rake lol
touch /1
touch: cannot touch ?/1?: Permission denied
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [touch /1...]

Tasks: TOP => lol
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Никаких трейсов.
Что-то у вас не так, смотрите дотфайлы.